# "set completion-ignore-case on " ignored in ~/.inputrc

Tags: bash, macos, readline

I'm attempting to set `completion-ignore-case on` in my `~/.inputrc`, but the option seems to be ignored. When I hit tab, only case-sensitive matches are shown.

Here's my `~/.inputrc`:

```
# Bash input configuration
set completion-ignore-case on     #Enable case-insensitive tab-complete
"\e[A": history-search-backward   #Press up or down arrow to search through shell history on what you've already typed
"\e[B": history-search-forward

#"\e[1;9C": forward-word          #alt-left/right to move the cursor by words
#"\e[1;9D": backward-word         #I prefer to enable this in iTerm settings so it works no matter where I'm ssh'd to.
```

Oddly enough, the `history-search-backward` and `-forward` settings **do** work, so `~/.inputrc` **is** getting read, but `completion-ignore-case` is getting ignored somehow.

Running `bind "set completion-ignore-case on"` yields the expected behavior. I also tried `set`-ing other variables in `~/.inputrc` and they also worked fine.

I'm running MacOS 10.12.4 and bash 4.4.12(1)-release (installed via homebrew).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to remove the comment. This seems to make it work for me.

```
# Bash input configuration
set completion-ignore-case on
"\e[A": history-search-backward   #Press up or down arrow to search through shell history on what you've already typed
"\e[B": history-search-forward

#"\e[1;9C": forward-word          #alt-left/right to move the cursor by words
#"\e[1;9D": backward-word         #I prefer to enable this in iTerm settings so it works no matter where I'm ssh'd to.
```

Comment: *facepalm* I can't believe that was the problem. Turns out you can't have comments on the same line as commands in inputrc.