# Entries in ~/.inputrc are being ignored

Tags: bash, shell, centos7, readline

I have a nearly identical situation as described in
[why-is-my-readline-inputrc-configuration-being-ignored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487037/) and
["set completion-ignore-case on" ignored in inputrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102223/), but the issues there were resolved by removing inline comments from the `~/.inputrc` file, whereas mine has no comments at all.

Here are the contents of my `~/.inputrc`:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Neither of the lines have any effect. This is on a server running CentOS 7, which I SSH into for work. Oddly, these settings used to work for years until today. I'm not sure what kind of configuration would cause this to no longer work, or override my `~/.inputrc` but I'm hoping someone might know.

At this point, I've simply added `bind` commands for both of these settings to my `~/.bashrc`, which works, so this question is more of a discovery query since I'm fine with the workaround.

Comment: your bash version?

Comment: You don't have an INPUTRC environmental variable referencing another file?

Comment: @pynexj, I am using bash 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: @RamanSailopal No, I do not have an INPUTRC environmental variable referencing another file.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the issue was. I'm not sure how it happened, but at some point, my `~/.inputrc` file was saved using CR/LF line endings. The `readline` parser does not like the extra line feed, apparently causing it to ignore the entire line.  Hopefully this information is useful to someone else in the future.